# Broken feed for the Cryptography site

Tags: bug, feed

For the past couple of days, the feed https://crypto.stackexchange.com/feeds hasn't been working in the [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird) feed reader... What is the reason?

Also the [W3C validator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service) returns problems:
https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcrypto.stackexchange.com%2Ffeeds, but I don't know if those are the causes for my Thunderbird problem (I never tried the validator before).

Comment: It's caused by 'strange' characters in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/98727/24869), so the problem will solve itself in a few days. Still, the feed generator should account for that, therefore I'm tagging this as a [tag:bug].