# Invalid XML characters in Stack Exchange sites' Atom feeds continue to pop

Tags: bug, feed, xml, atom

The issue is still not fixed and happened again with this feed:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=prestashop&sort=newest

https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffeeds%2Ftag%3Ftagnames%3Dprestashop%26sort%3Dnewest#l45

**This bug is not in the post, but in the Atom  XML generator used by Stack Exchange's web sites.**

This is the invalid XML portion:

```xml
<entry>
  <id>https://stackoverflow.com/q/71250009</id>
  <re:rank scheme="https://stackoverflow.com">-2</re:rank>
  <title type="text">Create PDF file from php ajax (post) request result in javascript</title>
  <category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="javascript"/>
  <category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="php"/>
  <category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="jquery"/>
  <category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="pdf"/>
  <category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="prestashop"/>
  <author>
    <name>jmauclair</name>
    <uri>https://stackoverflow.com/users/13470254</uri>
  </author>
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250009/create-pdf-file-from-php-ajax-post-request-result-in-javascript"/>
  <published>2022-02-24T09:46:07Z</published>
  <updated>2022-02-24T09:46:07Z</updated>
  <summary type="html">
    &lt;p&gt;I&#x27;ve been searching through the web but it seems that nobody is having the same issue as me.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I&#x27;m trying to create a pdf file from post request to a php file that return a PDF 1.7
    content.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Here is my code in js :&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt; function generateInvoices() {&#xA; $.post(invoiceGenerationURL, { order_id: ordersID }).done(function (data) {&#xA; document.write(data)&#xA;
    });&#xA;}&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I&#x27;m just writing the result to see what&#x27;s the output.&#xA;I&#x27;ve tried to use jsPDF, but it didn&#x27;t work and gave me an empty pdf file.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Here is my Php code
    :&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;if (isset($_POST[&#x27;order_id&#x27;])) {&#xA; $id_orders = json_decode($_POST[&#x27;order_id&#x27;]);&#xA; $pdfs = array();&#xA; foreach ($id_orders as $id_order) {&#xA; $order = new Order((int)
    $id_order);&#xA; if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order)) {&#xA; die(&#x27;The order cannot be found within your database for order :&#x27; . $id_order);&#xA; }&#xA;&#xA; $order_invoice_list = $order-&amp;gt;getInvoicesCollection();&#xA;
    Hook::exec(&#x27;actionPDFInvoiceRender&#x27;, [&#x27;order_invoice_list&#x27; =&amp;gt; $order_invoice_list]);&#xA;&#xA; $context = Context::getContext();&#xA;&#xA; $pdf = new PDF($order_invoice_list, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE,
    $context-&amp;gt;smarty);&#xA;&#xA; $pdfs[] = $pdf-&amp;gt;render(&#x27;I&#x27;);&#xA; }&#xA; return $pdfs; &#xA; }&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I&#x27;m creating an array of pdf files content to then generate a pdf with all the
    invoices in the same file, I&#x27;m on prestashop 1.7&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;This is the output :&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;%PDF-1.7 %&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD; 6 0 obj &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified
    (D:20220224103446&#x2B;01&#x27;00&#x27;) /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000
    595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 7 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB &amp;gt;&amp;gt; /Annots [ 5 0 R ] /PZ 1 &amp;gt;&amp;gt; endobj 7 0 obj
    &amp;lt;&amp;gt; stream x&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;][s&#xFFFD;F&#xFFFD;~&#x3EF;@&#x569;S&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;2&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;_&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;r&#x2523;(&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#x27;[&#xFFFD;}`$:&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;d&#x4A1;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;y&#x6DF;&#xFFFD;K&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;t
    0&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;(^&#x10;#&#x469;$p&#x13;&#xFFFD;|}&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;i&#xFFFD;Tj&#xFFFD;?&#x13;&#xFFFD;|&#xF;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;_&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;o&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#x7FE;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;2&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;5M(II&#xFFFD;&#x27;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;^~A6~&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xF;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;p&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;_&#xCB;&#xFFFD;o&#xFFFD;u&#xFFFD;&amp;amp;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;.&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;=&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;q^6&#xFFFD;$&#xFFFD;IB&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;C&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;n&amp;lt;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;O&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;y&#x763;&#xFFFD;UdCn&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;I&#xFFFD;PB&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xE;&#xFFFD;&#x19E;#jS&#x27;22K&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;s&#xFFFD;0&#xFFFD;
    FX*(&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;{M&amp;lt;&#x633;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;;P&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;?&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;b&#xFFFD;[&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;,&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;7&amp;quot;&#xFFFD;Y&#xFFFD;*n&#xFFFD;d(O
    3Z&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;:&#xFFFD;&#x75EF;O^^&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;8&#xFFFD;&#x6FF;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;Z&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;p&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;u&#xFFFD;Bw&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#x63C;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;PkS&#xFFFD;e&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;4&#xFFFD;l?IQ&#xFFFD;*b&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;lE&#xFFFD;PR&#xFFFD;U&#xFFFD;d&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;F&#xFFFD;&amp;quot;&#xFFFD;&#x2B;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;,,&#xFFFD;&#x423;&#xFFFD;8&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;(&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;lV(,&#x6A6;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;z}dI&#xFFFD;3&#xFFFD;&#x7BD;tO&#xFFFD;_?&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;...data...&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#x1CF;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#x2F5;j&#x4E6;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;u&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;Td&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;.&#xFFFD;{&#xFFFD;9&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;M@&#xFFFD;xK&#x4C8;,&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#x666;Bi&#xFFFD;5&#xFFFD;&#x6A6;/4.4&#xFFFD;Q&#xFFFD;i&#xFFFD;&#xE;&#xFFFD;V&#xFFFD;s&#xFFFD;Pg&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;7&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;G&#xFFFD;&#x41C;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;)#Y&#xFFFD;M~jq&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;de&#xFFFD;~!!&#xFFFD;_&#xFFFD;@&#xFFFD;&#xF;
    endstream endobj 2 0 obj &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /F1 3 0 R /F2 4 0 R &amp;gt;&amp;gt; /XObject &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /I0 8 0 R /I1 9 0 R /I2 10 0 R /I3 11 0 R /I4 12 0 R /I5 13 0 R /I6 14 0 R
    /I7 15 0 R /I8 16 0 R /I9 17 0 R /I10 18 0 R /I11 19 0 R &amp;gt;&amp;gt; &amp;gt;&amp;gt; endobj 5 0 obj &amp;lt;&amp;gt; /H /I&amp;gt;&amp;gt; endobj 20 0 obj &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /Producer (&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD;TCPDF 6.3.2 \(http://www.tcpdf.org\))
    /CreationDate (D:20220224103446&#x2B;01&#x27;00&#x27;) /ModDate (D:20220224103446&#x2B;01&#x27;00&#x27;) /Trapped /False &amp;gt;&amp;gt; endobj 21 0 obj &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /Type /Metadata /Subtype /XML /Length 4223 &amp;gt;&amp;gt; stream
    application/pdf 2022-02-24T10:34:46&#x2B;01:00 2022-02-24T10:34:46&#x2B;01:00 2022-02-24T10:34:46&#x2B;01:00 TCPDF 6.3.2 (http://www.tcpdf.org) uuid:32a9224a-f541-2ff9-5709-cc9cd0bf3a56 uuid:32a9224a-f541-2ff9-5709-cc9cd0bf3a56
    http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/ pdf Adobe PDF Schema http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/ xmpMM XMP Media Management Schema internal UUID based identifier for specific incarnation of a document InstanceID URI http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/ pdfaid PDF/A ID
    Schema internal Part of PDF/A standard part Integer internal Amendment of PDF/A standard amd Text internal Conformance level of PDF/A standard conformance Text endstream endobj 22 0 obj &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /Type /Catalog /Version /1.7 /Pages 1 0 R
    /Names &amp;lt;&amp;lt; &amp;gt;&amp;gt; /ViewerPreferences &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /Direction /L2R &amp;gt;&amp;gt; /PageLayout /SinglePage /PageMode /UseNone /OpenAction [6 0 R /FitH null] /Metadata 21 0 R &amp;gt;&amp;gt; endobj xref 0 23 0000000000
    65535 f 0000008325 00000 n 0000020164 00000 n 0000008384 00000 n 0000008490 00000 n 0000020410 00000 n 0000000015 00000 n 0000000483 00000 n 0000008601 00000 n 0000008872 00000 n 0000010321 00000 n 0000010593 00000 n 0000012132 00000 n 0000012404
    00000 n 0000014038 00000 n 0000014310 00000 n 0000016027 00000 n 0000016299 00000 n 0000018130 00000 n 0000018402 00000 n 0000020626 00000 n 0000020824 00000 n 0000025130 00000 n trailer &amp;lt;&amp;lt; /Size 23 /Root 22 0 R /Info 20 0 R /ID [
    &amp;lt;32a9224af5412ff95709cc9cd0bf3a56&amp;gt; &amp;lt;32a9224af5412ff95709cc9cd0bf3a56&amp;gt; ] &amp;gt;&amp;gt; startxref 25339 %%EOF&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;The result is badly encoded whereas this is set in the php header
    :&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt; header(&#x27;Content-Type: application/pdf&#x27;);&#xA; if (headers_sent()) {&#xA; $this-&amp;gt;Error(&#x27;Some data has already been output to browser, can\&#x27;t send PDF file&#x27;);&#xA; }&#xA;
    header(&#x27;Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=1&#x27;);&#xA; //header(&#x27;Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0&#x27;); // HTTP/1.1&#xA; header(&#x27;Pragma: public&#x27;);&#xA;
    header(&#x27;Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT&#x27;); // Date in the past&#xA; header(&#x27;Last-Modified: &#x27;.gmdate(&#x27;D, d M Y H:i:s&#x27;).&#x27; GMT&#x27;);&#xA; header(&#x27;Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename=&amp;quot;&#x27;.basename($name).&#x27;&amp;quot;&#x27;);&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I don&#x27;t really find out what is wrong, and how to get the pdf value of each pdf invoices to merge it in only one pdf
    file.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I&#x27;m not an expert in Javascript and Jquery.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;
  </summary>
</entry>
```

Related simlar reports:

- *[Invalid XML in Atom feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220871/479836)*
- *[Invalid characters in XML Atom feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374806/479836)*

---

<sub>This was moved here as a new post [by request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220871/invalid-xml-in-atom-feed/376583#comment1255162_376583) from [@Slate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1037447/slate):</sub>

<sub>*Hey, could I ask you to drop this info into a new question? [status-completed] is pretty much a 'report closed' tag, especially for issues originally addressed in 2014. Happy to drop the appropriate escalation tags on your report once it's in a new question.*</sub>

Comment: Possibly related recent question: *[Broken feed for the Cryptography site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376440/)*

Comment: I think you ought to delete [this answer too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374797/188189) and incorporate it here if you think it necessary.

Comment: Hey, this is totally my bad - I didn't realize you'd already posted another question about this issue when I recommended moving it into an answer. I've marked this as a duplicate, and I'm going to poke a developer and see if we can get a bit more information about the possible timeline. You're also not the only one who's reported this, so I'm gonna make your first post a bit of a collector for the issue. If you think this is an error, please let me know, happy to correct.